# How to break axis in R/ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following

```
library(ggplot2)

scale_y_continuous(name="ds", limits=c(0, 4), breaks=c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,
1.5,1.75,2,2.25,2.5,2.75,3,3.25,3.5,3.75,4)
```

As you can see, I want the y-axis to go from 0 to 4 in intervals of 0.25. I was just wondering if there is a smerter way to type it rather than typing all the y-axis values.

Best regards,
C.

Comment: Maybe use `seq()`?